# Problemas Conectar PHP con Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

Estoy trabajando con PHP, siempre he utilizado MYSQL pero ahora tuve que hacer un cambio y comencé a utilizar ORACLE XE y SQL DEVELOPER 22. En mi sistema tengo un input en donde ingreso parte del Rut de una persona y enseguida se despliegan los diferentes Rut para seleccionar. Todo esto me funciona bien solo en MYSQL pero hasta ahora no he logrado aplicarlo a ORACLE.
Mi problema es que ejecuto mi pagina e ingreso un Rut, pero no se carga nada, ni tampoco me muestra error para saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Les comparto mi código para que por favor me puedan ayudar e indicar donde esta el error.

Lo primero es mi pagina PHP dbcontroller_oracle.php en donde tengo la función para la conexión a la base de datos:

```
   class DBControllerOracle {
   private $user = "SYSTEM";
   private $password = "root";
   private $database = "localhost/XE";
   private $conn;

   function __construct() {
    $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
   }

   function connectDB() {
   $conn = oci_connect($this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
   return $conn;
   }

   function runQuery($query) {  
   $result = oci_parse($this->conn,$query);
   while($row=oci_fetch_array($result)) {  ******* en esta linea tengo el error. ORA-24374: definicion no realizada antes de recuperar o de ejecutar y recuperar in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sistema\\sistema\\dbcontroller_oracle.php on line 19,

   $resultset[] = $row;
   }
   if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
   }
   }
```

En otra pagina donde ejecuto la misma función pero para MYSQL, el código de la función es el siguiente:

```
  function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
  }
```

Les agrego esto porque creo que quizás aquí esta el error.

Y después tengo mi pagina alumno en donde paso el Rut que ingresa un usuario y hago la conexion con la Query.

```
 <?php 
   if (isset($_GET['term']))
   {
      include('./dbcontroller_oracle.php');
      $db_handle = new DBControllerOracle();

      $return_arr = array();

      $sql = "SELECT nombres, rut, apellidos, correo FROM alumno WHERE rut like '%".$_GET['term']."%' LIMIT 5";

      $faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);

      foreach($faq as $k=>$v)  ***** en esta linea tengo el error argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sistema\\sistema\\alumno.php on line 15
      { 
         $row_array['value'] = $faq[$k]['rut'];
         $row_array['rut']=$faq[$k]['rut'];
         $row_array['nombres']=$faq[$k]['nombres'];
         $row_array['apellidos']=$faq[$k]['apellidos'];

         array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
      }
      echo json_encode($return_arr);
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste OCI8? ¿Qué dice el log?

Comment: Edite la pregunta, estoy utilizando ORACLE XE y SQLDEVELOPER 22

Comment: Gracias, edite la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas a SYSTEM? Esas credenciales te funcionan conectándote desde otro cliente? Si es así, en esa sesión puedes ver la tabla que buscas??? Tienes las tablas creadas en el esquema SYSTEM??

Comment: Esas credenciales ya las validé desde un archivo php que cree para hacer pruebas, y me conecta bien a la base de datos y la tabla me muestra datos

Comment: Cuál es el contenido de `$_GET['term']` con el que estás probando?

Comment: Es cualquier Rut que se ingresa en el input

Comment: Ni idea que será "cualquier rut" y ni idea cuál será el input del que hablas. No asumas que todos saben lo que tú sabes. Edité la respuesta con otra aproximación. Todo indica que en tu manejador no se están controlando excepciones y algo hace que tu consulta no se ejecute. O es la conexión o es la consulta en sí.

Comment: recomiendo un dump y debug desde la respuesta de runQuery... validar el contenido de cada variable en direccion inversa para ver en que punto seja de funcionar , estoyu casi seguro de que el problema es el query o el resultado el query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré el problema, era el LIMIT en la Query, lo quité y funciono. LIMIT no existe en ORACLE, lo reemplace con ROWNUM.

Queda de la siguiente manera:

$sql = "SELECT NOMBRES, RUT, APELLIDOS, CORREO FROM ALUMNO WHERE RUT like '%".$_GET['term']."%' and ROWNUM <= 5";

El resto se mantiene tal cual.

Answer (score 1):

En la clase donde ejecutas las consultas Oracle te falta ejecutar la consulta con [`oci_execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php).

Actualmente tienes

```
function runQuery($query) {
   $result = oci_parse($this->conn,$query);
   while($row=oci_fetch_array($result)) {
   $resultset[] = $row;
   }
   if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
   }
}
```

Ahí recibes la consulta, le haces el `oci_parse` por si toca prepararla y eso. Luego haces un fetch pero pues... no has ejecutado nada. Va a ser vacío y el error en el foreach es porque estás intentando iterar sobre una variable nula.

```
function runQuery($query) {
   $result = oci_parse($this->conn,$query);
   oci_execute($result);

   while($row=oci_fetch_array($result)) {
       $resultset[] = $row;
   }
   if(!empty($resultset))
       return $resultset;
   }
   // Yo controlaría el else y retornaría algo predecible si el arreglo está vacío...
}
```

**EDITO** Yo, además, no haría esa concatenación del GET directo en la consulta. Eso es vulnerable a SQL injection y es una pésima práctica. De paso, puede que tengas problemas con el contenido del GET porque no esté escapado o meta carácteres raros que rompan la consulta y generen todo este lío.

Podrías seguir [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) y poner los parámetros de una mejor forma.

Tendrías que editar la página alumno cambiando la consulta pa usar placeholders. Parámetros. Así no concatenas nada.

```
$sql = "SELECT nombres, rut, apellidos, correo FROM alumno WHERE rut LIKE :p0 LIMIT 5";
```

Y crear un array con los parámetros de la consulta

`$arrayParams[0] = "%$_GET['term']%";`

Para entregárselo a la ejecución de la consulta

```
$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sql, $arrayParams);
```

Luego, enviarle el array de parámetros al método de tu manejador de conexión

```
function runQuery($query, $paramArray) {
...
    $result = oci_parse($this->conn,$query);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':p0', $paramArray[0]);
    oci_execute($result);
    ...
```

Y usar el binding pa meter los parámetros de forma segura. De paso, te ahorras líos con caracteres no escapados y cosas horrendas

Comment: Me muestra los errores anteriores y agrega oci_execute(): ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente

Comment: Muestra el siguiente error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function DBControllerOracle::runQuery(), 1 passed

Comment: @SBK22 no sé cómo integraste la sugerencia a tu código, así que no sé qué hiciste y cómo le terminaste entregando los parámetros. Si copiaste y pegaste, no va a funcionar. Edita tu pregunta e indica cómo integraste la solución propuesta en tu código. No nos pongas a adivinar, por favor

Comment: Tienes Razón, edite la pregunta y coloque el código que modifique, muchas gracias por tu ayuda e interés en resolver esto.

Comment: @SBK22 fíjate que tienes que entregar el array de parámetros a la función runQuery. Como te muestro en el ejemplo, tienes que crearlo y entregárselo. Edité nuevamente para hacerlo más claro

Comment: Estoy modificando el código, pero $arrayParams[0] = $_GET..., la verdad no entiendo bien como configurarlo

Comment: Agregue los códigos, pero me no reconoce la variable $stid

Comment: @SBK22 usé el ejemplo en la documentación y por eso se fue con la variable incorrecta, pero ya lo edité. También sugiero que revises la documentación que enlacé en la respuesta para que entiendas qué está pasando

Comment: Edite la pregunta nuevamente, y coloque el codigo que configure, pero me muestra varios errores:

Comment: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number ///// oci_execute(): ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente ///// oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: definicion no realizada antes de recuperar o de ejecutar y recuperar //////  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Comment: @SBK22 Último intento teniendo en cuent que no hago nada en PHP hace como diez años :P Probemos cambiando la forma como haces el LIKE. Arma la cadena con el GET y los `%` y se la entregas como parámetro. El binding no necesita las comillas simples tampoco. A ver si así deja de romperse la consulta y se ejecuta :)

Comment: Muestra los mismos errores, pero te agradezco el esfuerzo por intentar encontrar una solución. Seguiré buscando resolver esto.

Comment: finalmente lo resolví, era el LIMIT en la QUERY el problema, lo quite y funcionó. Buscaré como agregar LIMIT para ORACLE.